# Set wordpress category to sub-domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have custom taxonomy http://thedripple.com/country/india and I want to show this category when someone opens http://in.thedripple.com. I guess this can be done using htaccess, I tried the following code but it didn't worked. any other option? I want to keep the subdomain in the address bar.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^in.thedripple.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /country/india/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the magic:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^country/india(.*)$ http://in.thedripple.com [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^country/india/(.*)$ http://in.thedripple.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmm... It should work; I've tested it again. Is it giving you any error message or it does redirect you somewhere?

Comment: Its showing
Great Success ! 
Apache is working on your cPanel® and WHM™ Server page

I've created subdomain...should I delete the subdomain? and try?

Comment: Yes, it won't work if you have subdomain already. I think it is better to keep your subdomain alive. Here you can see tweaks for the case with subdomain with all details as needed: http://www.werockyourweb.com/redirect-folder-to-subdomain